# Auto Update Table of Contents in Word when saving as PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

Every time I save my document as PDF I get this dialog (multiple times since I have table of contents for each section). Is there a setting to automatically update all tables of contents and avoid these messages?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A macro seems to be the only way to update all the TOCs and avoid these annoying messages. Helpfully someone has wrote one to do just this already which can be found on the [Microsoft forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/word-2010-macro-to-automatically-update-toc/77c3632b-24f2-47c9-a6be-da9573d4742d?auth=1). I have copied it here in case the link ever goes down.

```
Sub UpdateDocument()
    Dim oStory As Range
    Dim oTOC As TableOfContents
    Dim oTOF As TableOfFigures
      For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        oStory.Fields.Update
        If oStory.StoryType  wdMainTextStory Then
          While Not (oStory.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
            Set oStory = oStory.NextStoryRange
            oStory.Fields.Update
          Wend
        End If
      Next oStory
    For Each oTOC In ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents
            oTOC.Update
        Next oTOC
    For Each oTOF In ActiveDocument.TablesOfFigures
            oTOF.Update
        Next oTOF
        ActiveDocument.Save
End Sub
```